# PostgreSQL timestamp with time zone show incorrect time

Tags: c#, postgresql

Inserting method:

```
instruction.created_at = DateTime.Now;
instruction.updated_at = DateTime.Now;
var entity = await unitOfWork.instructions.InsertAsync(instruction, user_with_credentials.id);
```

---

postgre SQL data created_at: 2021-12-16 17:47:11.24496+00-Right

swagger data created_at: 2021-12-16T23:47:11.24496+06:00 -Wrong

---

Updating method:

```
instruction.updated_at = DateTime.Now;
unitOfWork.instructions.Update(instruction, user_with_credentials.id);
```

When update same object/row 2-3 times, to date create_at add 2-3 day, because per time create_at add 6 hour when get from rest api.
I' m going to block input value created_at column, get from db, and set per time manually.
May be has any other solution?
How to solve it?

Comment: How is swagger involved here? When saving datetime its always a good idea to use a common timezone. Using Now is in almost all cases a problem. It means different things in different timezones. Without knowing to much of the details here. You should consider explicitly using a concret timezone. Easiests ist using UtcNow instead of Now.  And then if needed calculate the concrete timezones time of the "viewer" of the data.

Comment: The difference in time is only one hour.  The culture for the timezone may be wrong.  One time may be using Daylight savings time and the other may not have Daylight savings time.  Some countries use Daylight savings time and others do not.

Comment: They are  the same time, just expressed in different time zone offsets. What is the field type for `create_at`, `timestamp` or `timestamp with time zone`?

Comment: Timestamp with time zone. I changed to timestamp without time zone and everything got better.